# Store all subdirectories of /Volumes in an array (BASH)

Tags: arrays, bash

I need a script that will get all of the directories within the /Volumes directory on a Mac and store them in an array. The problem that I am running into is that it is very common for there to be a space in a directory name, and that really messes things up. 
Here is what I've got so far:

```
LOCATION="/Volumes"
COUNTER=0
cd $LOCATION
OIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'

for folder in *; do
[ -d "$folder" ] || continue
(( DRIVES[$COUNTER] = ${folder} ))
(( COUNTER = COUNTER + 1 ))
done
IFS=$OIFS
```

Here is the error that I am getting:

```
./getDrives.sh: line 17: DRIVES[0] = Macintosh HD : syntax error in expression (error token is "HD ")
```

Comment: Put double quotes around your parameter expansions, like "$folder".

Comment: I have tried that. I have also tried "$(folder)" and "${folder}" with no success. Same error for all of them.

Comment: remove the spaces around the `=` sign. You can also get your increment with `(( COUNTER++ ))` . Good luck.

Comment: Try `DRIVES[$COUNTER]="$folder"`.

Comment: And there seems no purpose in changing `IFS`.

Comment: Removing the spaces didn't have any effect. I was changing the IFS because I was hoping that it would stop the space from messing things up, but obviously it didn't so I went ahead and took it out.

Comment: `(( ))` puts the shell into a math context. If you aren't dealing with numbers, it doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the simplest is just:

```
array=( /Volumes/*/ )
```

Notes:

- use this with `nullglob` or `failglob` set
- if you also want hidden directories (but not `.` nor `..`), set `dotglob`
- if you want all the directories and subdirectories (recursively), set `globstar` and use

  ```
  array=( /Volumes/**/ )
  ```

  instead.

---

When I say *set `nullglob` or `failglob` or `dotglob` or `globstar`* I mean the shell options, that can be set with, e.g.:

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

and unset with, e.g.:

```
shopt -u nullglob
```

More about these in [*The Shopt Builtin* section of the Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Shopt-Builtin).

---

To answer your comment: you only want the basename of the directories, not the full path? easy, just do

```
cd /Volumes
array=( */ )
```

That's all. In fact, I'm suggesting you replace 6 lines of inefficient code with just one, much more efficient, line.

More generally, if you don't want to `cd` into `/Volumes`, you can easily get rid of the leading `/Volumes/` like so

```
array=( /Volumes/*/ )
array=( "${array[@]/#\/Volumes\//}" )
```

Or, even better, put the leading `/Volumes/` in a variable and proceed as:

```
location="/Volumes/"
array=( "$location"* )
array=( "${array[@]/#"$location"/}" )
```

Comment: This does work, but I am going to stick with the solution that Ooga and I were using purely because it puts only the directory name into the array. This method puts the full path.

Comment: ...or, to avoid the `cd`: `array=( /Volumes/* ); array=( "${array[@]##*/}" )`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That's a bit broken since OP wants directories, so it needs to be `array=( /Volumes/*/ )` (trailing slash) and then `array=( "${array[@]##*/}" )` would make all the terms the empty string. I've added a way to do it along these lines, though, thanks.

Comment: Ok, you are right here. That last bit of code that you added does everything that I needed and it is much better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /Volumes

cnt=0
for d in *; do
  [ -d "$d" ] || continue
  drv[$cnt]="$d"
  ((++cnt))
done

for d in "${drv[@]}"; do
  echo "$d"
done
```

Comment: Ok, this is essentially the same as my code, but the 6th line (9th line for my code) does not have the double parentheses around it. That is what was causing it to break, so I took them out of my code and now it works perfectly. Thanks!